# Python 3.5 shows @ as matrix multiplication. How to use it?

Tags: python-3.x, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to figure out how to use matrix multiplication, operator @ in Python, listed in https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html, but I can´t find any example or make it work with lists.

How to use it?

Comment: Are you referring to [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations)? "The @ (at) operator is intended to be used for matrix multiplication." Because literally the next sentence says, "No builtin Python types implement this operator."

Comment: If you want robust support for matrix multiplication at this point, you should probably be using something like [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently no builtin type uses the `@` operator. You can define your own types to implement it by the `__matmul__` magic word. Here is a basic example:

```
class Mx:
  def __matmul__(self, other):
    return "matmul {0} {1}".format(self, other)

print(Mx() @ 0)
```